# JMS QueueReceiver - Need to keep receiver wait for sometime even messages are available on Queue

Tags: jms

I have to update my existing JMS Receiver program to as follows.

Existing Functionality:

- My receiver class will read a message and calls a web service to process the job in one of the server once the message is received as xml.

  New Functionality:
- The receiver should wait for sometime until the job server is free to process a job. I tried using MessageSelectors but which is only applicable for message headers.I tried this option "message = (JMSTextMessage) mqQueueReceiver.receive(100000000000000);" but whenever i posted a message those message is read after posted into queue. But i want to keep receiver to wait for some interval which i am getting from Job server through web service call.

My Code is below:

```
        connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHostName(config.getValue("host"));
        connectionFactory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(config.getValue("port")));
        connectionFactory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
        connectionFactory.setQueueManager(config.getValue("manager"));
        connectionFactory.setChannel(config.getValue("channel"));
        queueConnection =  (MQQueueConnection) connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
                    queueSession = (MQQueueSession) queueConnection.createQueueSession(true, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        queue = (MQQueue) queueSession.createQueue(config.getValue("queue"));
        mqQueueReceiver = (MQQueueReceiver) queueSession.createReceiver(queue);
```

while(true) {

```
        if(this.stopListener) {
            System.out.println("stopListener variable is changed ");
            break;
        }

        try {
        
            message = (JMSTextMessage) mqQueueReceiver.receive(1000);
        
            String response = "";
        
            if(this.nullCheckJMSTextObject(message)) {
            
                response= soapClient.invokeWebService(message.getText(),message.getJMSCorrelationID());

                                if(this.nullCheckSoapResponse(response)) {

                    queueSession.commit();
                    
                } else {
                                                
                    queueSession.rollback();
                    queueSession.commit();
                     Thread.sleep(receiverWaitTime);
                }
            }   

        } catch (JMSException e) {
        System.err.println("Linked Exception");
        e.getLinkedException();
        System.err.println("Error Code");
        e.getErrorCode();
        System.err.println("Cause ");
        e.getCause();
        System.err.println("fillTrackTrace ");
        e.fillInStackTrace();
            e.printStackTrace();
        break;
        }catch(IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();    
        break;
        }catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        break;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        break;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `receive(timeout)` method will wait for the specified timeout period for a message to arrive on a queue. If a message arrives on a queue before the timeout, the method will return immediately with a message otherwise the method will wait till the timeout period and then return with no message. You will see a 2033 exception.

The `timeout` specified for the `receive()` call indicates how long the `receive` method must wait for messages before it can return. The timeout specified is not to delay the message delivery. If there is a message, the method will return immediately.

I think your logic can be modified to alter the order of execution. Change the code to receive messages only when your web service is ready to process messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using different logic to solve this problem. I used rollback() to resolve it !!!!